# Installing 15.04 on X250 is not supported by lenovo

Tags: 15.04, lenovo, windows-10

Here is a summary:

According to Lenovo Tech support, it is no longer possible to boot from a memory stick (i.e., a ubuntu boot stick) once you upgrade to Windows 10.
Microsoft has locked out ubuntu starting with Windows 10, according to the Lenovo software support person I spoke with.

Details:
I bought two Lenovo X250 computers in July 2015. They came with Windows 8.1 preinstalled. For computer A I swapped out the hard drive with a 250GB solid state drive, and proceed to install Ubuntu 15.04. This was a bit of a pain, but it eventually worked. There was no problem booting the iso memory stick with the 15.04 image on it once I modified the BIOS.

On the second compuber B, I upgraded to Windows 10. Once the upgrade was installed I was not able to book the memory stick, regardless of the BIOS settings. So, I called Lenovo support, and after a somewhat intelligent conversation, they told me it was not possible. The only way I could boot the ubuntu memory stick would be to install Windows 8 from a recovery drive. But, I said, I wont be able to boot that because I cant boot from the USB stick. They said "dont worry it will work, as long as the memory stick/cdrom/DVD boot drive has a supported Windows 8. They said "the computer knows its supportd media."

Is everyone aware of this situation, or is only me that is in the dark.

Or did I ask the wrong question, or need to do more surfing of the internet?

Please help. This sounds serious, and a policy change that is pretty fundamental.

Please dont ask "did you turn off secure boot?" That is not a helpful question/comment.

If you know how to boot a Ubuntu 15.04 memory stick, on a Lenovo X250 or equivalent, then please let me know and I'll try your solution.

Jont

Comment: Are you saying that a usb boot option isn't available (F12 on my Lenovo) or it's there but refuses (or doesn't recognize?) to boot an Ubuntu usb? If the later have you tried a 14.04.3 image?

Comment: When I try to boot  sys B (the one upgraded from  8 to  10) via ubuntu 15.04 USB stick,  I hold down F12,  into the boot select menu. I then select the FDD portion of the USB stick, and it starts to boot. The screen goes black, & it says "Insecure boot."   Following that, it hangs up for at least 1 min, finally it goes back to Windows 10,  never boots the memory stick. When I do the same on  my X250 System A, it does the same, BUT it does not hang. Rather it boots into Ubuntu 15.04.   Lenovo service said I must reinstall 8.1 to get it to boot off the memory stick.

Comment: Interesting, maybe I'll try upgrading my lenovo y510p w/ win 8.1 to win 10 next week & see what happens. As far as I know Ubuntu has a signed EFI boot loader so this should not be a problem. Did you try 14.04.3? Over at ubuntu forums I can't recollect anyone complaining of this issue with win 10 in general.

Comment: Doug, I'll be interested in what you find. Please let me know. I really want to boot ubuntu on the Win10 system. And yes I tried 14.04, and got the same result. The thing is that 14.04 does not play well with the X250. Something is wrong with the mouse. Not sure, but the solution is to use 15.04 which works perfectly.  Thanks for you interest. I consider this a super threat to linux on Lenovo. Service stated that the USB stick will not boot from Win10. so there you go.

Comment: I recommend that you call Lenovo software support and confirm what they told me. I didnt need to wait on the phone long, they responded quickly.  Their number is 1-855-500-1051. They did not request a warrantee number once I explained the very general nature of my question.

Comment: Did you manage to install ubuntu eventually? I am just waiting to receive my laptop next week. I assumed obvious that it's going to work with it. This article says that it should work http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201501-16339/

Comment: If you could post those BIOS settings in here that would be sweet! I came across this post looking for help setting my Lenovo x250 BIOS to optimal for Debian based distro's.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get 14.04 and 15.10 booted and working. The real problem was very subtle, and it boiled down to the synaptics mouse-pad driver.

The question of the boot option was not really an issue. I was able to work
around the boot, by following the right rules. If you send me email, I can walk you through this problem. Its a mater of setting up the correct BIOS options, then you can install linux, no problem.

The mousepad synaptics driver was a different story. It is broken, and you must remove it, which is not hard.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1506817

That I worked out too, but it took months. Now my X250 it is all working. I still have a hardware issue, but that has nothing to do with linux.

Comment: So, what tech support told you was totally incorrect?

Comment: Do you have any tips/links/guides for ubuntu installation on X250? I'd really appriciate if you can make a small guide on it. My x250 is on it's way now.

Comment: I am presently using ubuntu 16.04.1-LTS on my Lenovo X250. The problems you can anticipate are the correct bios settings, for booting

Answer (score 0):

The tech support told me that Linux was not supported. That I suspect is true.
She led me to believe (and I asked) that Linux would not boot once Windows 10 was installed on the X250. This a germ of truth to it, but I did get it to book, eventually. As I indicated above, there was (and likely still is) a very subtle bug the synaptic mouse driver. This is all explained in the bug report mentioned above:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1506817

The solution to this problem is explained in this report. However in the end, you will not find the mouse-pad functional. The three mouse buttons will work, and the red mouse button will work. I didn't like the synaptic touch pad so I don't miss that. If you need it, you will need to work that out on your own. 
In my view, the synaptic driver is broken. Getting Synaptic (the company) to fix this, would be awesome, but I suspect, unlikely.